# jquery.sortable driving me nuts

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

i'm trying to make a set of elements sortable. Each element is created after an ajax request, so basically nothing in the DOM is available to bind sortable() on DOM ready. 
I managed to set a callback occuring after my json manipulations have ended and the dom is updated.

Here's a preview of what i'm doing now.

http://jsfiddle.net/zrFsT/

Am I missing something ? What could it be ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: did you save y0our jsfiddle. I see nothing about sortable in here right now.

Comment: changed the jsfiddle link. sorry

Comment: This jsfiddle will not work without a reference to the sortable plugin code.

Comment: and updated again. really sorry, not using jsfiddle enough ...

Comment: doesn't seem to be anything wrong to me - other than there not being a reference to the JqUI.  Add that to the HTML portion and it's golden.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing jquery-ui from the jsfiddle.

I've added it here: http://jsfiddle.net/zrFsT/

And updated your question.

Is this all that was wrong or are you trying to accomplish more?

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/zrFsT/1/

Removed multiple "lines" and the connect with feature usage.

Comment: Well, behaviour here is indeed better. But not what I expected. Sortable behaviour is supposed to work across one or many lines all together right ?

Comment: Oh wow, why are you doing that, you don't need each line in set lines just stack them all together with a width on the parent, use wrapping to get each line: http://jsfiddle.net/zrFsT/1/

Comment: Basically you could move one to another line but not place it in a certain place in the new "line". Connectwith connects each list but does not merge their sortable feature.

Comment: Okay, so maybe my problem is elsewhere : none of the code in the jsfiddle actually exists. I wonder if applying  $.sortable() on nodes not in the DOM on $.ready() could be the issue ?

Comment: sortable should be applied to a container of elements that needs sorting. Not sure what your code is doing, I can't see it. :)